# AWS - docker and jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins

I'm in the process of setting up jenkins to run through docker.  But seem to hit a road block.

Login through CLI verifies docker is installed and the jenkins image is installed.

```
docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hello-world         latest              fce289e99eb9        8 weeks ago         1.84kB
jenkins             latest              cd14cecfdb3a        7 months ago        696MB
```

setup the port

```
docker run -d -p 49001:8080 -v $PWD/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home:z -t jenkins
```

verified the container is running:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                NAMES
ff1f21312230        jenkins             "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49001->8080/tcp   nostalgic_mestorf
```

Checked if the host is accessible locally

```
curl localhost:49001
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>
```

attempting to connect to port 8080 doesn't work.

```
curl localhost:8080
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:8080; Connection refused
```

Running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo) on AWS

How do I allow access so that Jenkins loads up? What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You forwarded port 49001 to the Docker container's port 8080. That's how you access Jenkins. It looks like you got the right response for `curl localhost:49001`. It's asking you to login.

Also note the `jenkins` image is deprecated. You should use `jenkins/jenkins:lts` instead.